# How to stop bash function on error when called with shell operators && or ||

Tags: bash

I use `set -e` in bash scripts to stop on error. When I want to handle an error I typically use the || operator (i.e. `which git || echo "not found"`)

However, when I use the || operator after a function call `set -e` seems to be ignored inside the function.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

test() {
    false
    echo "This should not be printed!"
}

test || echo "test failed"
echo "Done"
```

Desired result is:

```
test failed
Done
```

but the actual result is

```
This should not be printed!
Done
```

When I just call `test` the script aborts on the `false` statement and prints nothing

The only (ugly) workaround I could come up with is to replace the call and error handling with:

```
set +e
(set -e; test)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "test failed"; fi
set -e
```

Is there a better way to get the desired behavior ([Edit] preferably without modifying the function)?

(Tested with git-bash on Windows and GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: @jens But I use `set -e`, and when I leave out the `|| echo "test failed"` part it will return the return code from `false`, hence my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `set -e` you have the be cautionus inside your function just as well as outside.

With `set -e` the shell basically translates

```
foo || bar
```

into

```
(set +e; foo) || bar
```

precisely because it needs to see the exit code from the end of the function.

The fix is to be similarly cautious inside the function definition.

```
# Renamed the function to as to avoid shadowing the test built-in
nst () {
    false || return
    echo "This should not be printed!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was kind of what I discovered, although I couldn't find a clear explanation of this behavior of bash. So I guess that in case I don't want to modify the function my workaround is as good as it gets?

Comment: I couldn't get it working in any other way. I need to examine the exit code in order to print 'test failed'. I can only get the exit code by disabling set -e, but I need to enable it for the function call itself.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was getting tangled up, you are correct, that's probably the way to go. I have deleted the confused comment you are replying to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the man page of bash. It says about `set -e` (emphasis by me):

> Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple
>   command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above),  exits
>   with  a  non- zero status.  **The shell does not exit if the command that
>   fails is** part of the command list immediately following a while or until
>   keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, **part of
>   any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the
>   final && or ||**, any command  in  a pipeline  but  the  last,  or if the
>   command's return value is being inverted with !.  If a compound command
>   other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed
>   while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if
>   set, is executed  before the  shell  exits.   This  option applies  to the
>   shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND
>   EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before
>   executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is
>   being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or
>   function  body  will  be  affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and
>   a command returns a failure status.  **If a compound command or shell function
>   sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will
>   not have any effect until the compound command or the command  containing
>   the  function call completes.**

In the following example, the second call to the function `test` will terminate the script, as it is the last command in a `||` list.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

test()
{
    false
    echo "This should not be printed!"
}

test || echo "test failed"
false || test
echo "Will not be printed"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation although I had to read it a couple of times to understand.